# pexpect error when trying to scp in a nohup process

Tags: scp, pexpect, nohup

I have an scp function as follows:

```
def scp_to38():
    child = pexpect.spawn(f"scp {tar_file_path} bbmprd@10.82.20.38:/app2/upload/")
    child.expect(f"bbmprd@10.82.20.38's password:")
    child.sendline("password")
    child.interact()
    print(f'{tar_file_path} SENT TO 38:/app2/upload/')
```

and it is throwing me an error saying a problem with child.interact()

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan_for_upload.py", line 39, in <module>
    scp_to38()
  File "scan_for_upload.py", line 26, in scp_to38
    child.interact()
  File "/app/anaconda3/envs/python37-1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 788, in interact
    mode = tty.tcgetattr(self.STDIN_FILENO)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

I am running the script in a nohup process, I believe that is causing this issue. Because when I run the script in the console, it works fine. How do I interact with the scp password in a nohup process using pexpect module? (I can't install any other external modules in my environment)

Comment: Instead of doing system calls, try this https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py

Comment: unfortunately, my environment does not have the scp package and cannot install any external package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interact()` is for manual interaction with the spawned process and it requires to be running on a tty but `nohup` provides no tty. You can just replace `child.interact()` with `child.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=None)`.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the scp worked, but the log gave an error message saying Timeout exceeded. Do you know why? Should I add something like child.close() or something at the end?

Comment: updated by adding one more `timeout` param. by default the timeout is 30 seconds.